# Can an entity in an entity-relationship diagram have more than one relationship?

Tags: database-design, erd

I am practicing drawing entity-relationsip diagrams and in the example it states *"many employees work on a project, and employee can work many projects but can only be assigned to at most one project at a given time."* Does the final statement after the *"but"* mean that there is another relationship?

Answer (score 2):

It means that time is an essential component of the relationship.  It's telling you that there's a functional dependency `(employee, time) -> project`.

In an entity-relationship diagram, I might model it like so:

[image: Assignment weak associative entity]

I made it a weak entity dependent on `Employee` and with `time` as a weak key, but it's still a relationship between `Employee` and `Project`, hence a weak associative entity.